# Convert pandas series into dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas series that I am trying to convert into a dataframe. The series is 1 col and 30 rows. I want to take every third element starting at index 0 and make it the first col of a new dataframe. Then i want to take the every third element starting at index 1 and make it the second col of a new dataframe.Then I want to take every third element starting at index 2 and make it the third col of a new dataframe.

My pandas series is:

```
dfTMP
Out[65]: 
1     14584416
2           96
3         2845
4     14112187
5           96
6         1629
7     12312225
8           77
9         4165
10    13466612
11          45
12        4146
13    12651673
14          27
15        1791
16    12565436
17          26
18        2956
19    14362965
20          26
21        3714
22    12352162
23          25
24        1689
25    12059502
26          25
27        2612
28    11659730
29          22
30        3771
Name: 4, dtype: int64
```

I tried the following:

```
    dfNEW = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['appID', 'rel', 'au']) # creates empty dataframe
    dfNEW['appID'] = dfTMP.iloc[0::3] # starting at 0, takes every 3rd element
    dfNEW['rel'] = dfTMP.iloc[1::3] # starting at 1, takes every 3rd element
    dfNEW['au'] = dfTMP.iloc[2::3] # starting at 2, takes every 3rd element
```

This code only creates the first col (or actually the slice of the series i copy first).

1. Why doesn't the above code work for all cols? I get nan for columns after the first col.
2. What is the proper way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code doesn't work because the indexing is wrong.  You could fix it by dropping the index and only using the values, like this:

```
dfNEW = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['appID', 'rel', 'au']) # creates empty dataframe
dfNEW['appID'] = dfTMP.iloc[0::3].values
# and so on
```

But a much more compact way that works in cases like your example is:

```
dfNEW = pd.DataFrame(dfTMP.values.reshape(-1,3), columns=['appID', 'rel', 'au'])
```

Comment: prefer your `.reshape(-1,3)` method rather than my explicit `len` answer

Comment: @EdChum: Both ways work on my machine, I tested with OP's sample input.

Answer (score 4):

Just `reshape` the numpy array of the `Series` by calling `reshape` on `.values` passing in the desired new dimensions and pass the array to the `DataFrame` ctor:

```
In[12]:
dfNEW = pd.DataFrame(s.values.reshape((10,3)),columns = ['appID', 'rel', 'au'])
dfNEW

Out[12]: 
      appID  rel    au
0  14584416   96  2845
1  14112187   96  1629
2  12312225   77  4165
3  13466612   45  4146
4  12651673   27  1791
5  12565436   26  2956
6  14362965   26  3714
7  12352162   25  1689
8  12059502   25  2612
9  11659730   22  3771
```

As for why it doesn't work `pandas` you have no existing index, so it can't align on another df, additionally your initial df is empty. You can't grow or append to a df using this method unless you either `reindex` to pre-allocate the rows, `append` to explicitly append the rows, or do a [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement).

Comment: Plus 1 for performing the transformation in NumPy world. To be more generic, you can use `-1` as first argument to `reshape`.

Comment: @jpp thanks have updated, don't like to cannibalise other answers so have added credit

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the pool:

```
dfNEW = pd.DataFrame()
dfNEW[['appID', 'rel', 'au']] = dfTMP.groupby(by=lambda x: x/3, axis=0).apply(tuple).apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: Super inefficient.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sure is, much slower than others, but does the job :)